# SQL : Group All

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate

I want to do the following pseudo-SQL:

```
SUM( SELECT a FROM tab WHERE b > 0);
```

This syntax doesn't work (at least not in sqlite), so I'm trying to figure out the proper phrasing.

```
SELECT SUM(a) FROM tab WHERE b > 0 GROUP BY (*); % nope
SELECT SUM(a) FROM tab WHERE b > 0 GROUP BY (1); % nope
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to find entirely duplicate rows? I'm not sure I understand what results you want from this.

Comment: @Cyrena: Nope.  Just trying to compute a sum of column values over a subset of the rows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's wrong with just `SELECT SUM(a) FROM tab WHERE b > 0`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT SUM(a) FROM tab GROUP BY (b > 0) HAVING (b > 0);
```